# Rainbow Array on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm having difficulties with arrays on Python, I need to make it so that the array is filled with colours from the rainbow such as Red. I then need to make the user input a integer between -1 and 7 which will then input a colour from the away e.g. -1 = Program ended and 3 = Yellow. My code is below and any help would be appreciated.

```
rainbow = ['Program Ended', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Indigo']

rainbow[0] = "1"

rainbow[1] = "2"

rainbow[2] = "3"

rainbow[3] = "4"

rainbow[4] = "5"

rainbow[5] = "6"

rainbow[6] = "7"

user_input = (int(input('Please input an interger from -1 to 7: ')))

print(user_input)
```

Comment: Hi Jaden,  you need to write the code, and let us know if you have any specific questions with it.  For starters though... your current code over-writes the 'rainbow' array with numbers... so your colours are lost forever.  Maybe a dictionary is more what you're looking for?

Comment: All this code does is print the user input - are you expecting us to write the entire thing for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example.

```
rainbow = ['Program Ended', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Indigo']

user_input = int(input("Please select a number between 1 and 6: "))

if user_input > 0 and user_input < 7:
    print(rainbow[user_input])
else:
    print("Program ended")
```

To capture a user's input, you simply invoke: input() function.

To access an array, you can do so by doing: rainbown[i], where i is the index of the array.

If you want me to clarify anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Example:

```
def pick_color(color):
    rainbow = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Indigo']
    if color == -1:
        print("Program Terminated")
    elif color > 0 and color <= len(rainbow):
        print(rainbow[color-1])
    else:
        print("Number out of range")

user_input = (int(input('Please input an interger from -1 to 6: ')))
pick_color(user_input)
```

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate this